# Changing the color of an AppBarButton on a Page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am trying to change the color of a single `AppBarButton` on a page

I can change it by setting these values in my `App.xaml` but they changes then throughout the app

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#66000000" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF3399FF" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#3D000000" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF000000" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF" />
```

So trying to set up a specific style that I can use whenever I want I use this and change the `Foreground` color in the `Setter` and also in the `VisualState Normal` but the only thing I see is the ring around the icon, the icon itself is missing and so is the text of the button

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
                <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.ItemType" Value="App Bar Button"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                            <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Width="100" Background="Transparent">
                                <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,12,0,11">
                                    <Grid Width="40" Height="40" Margin="0,0,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="BackgroundGlyph" Text="&#xE0A8;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="53.333" Margin="-4,-19,0,0" Foreground="{StaticResource AppBarItemBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="OutlineGlyph" Text="&#xE0A7;" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" FontSize="53.333" Margin="-4,-19,0,0"/>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-1,-1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                    <TextBlock
                            x:Name="TextLabel"
                            Text="{TemplateBinding Name}"
                            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            Margin="0,0,2,0"
                            FontSize="12"
                            TextAlignment="Center"
                            Width="88"
                            MaxHeight="32"
                            TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
                            Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <Rectangle
                            x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                            StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            StrokeDashOffset="1.5"/>
                                <Rectangle
                            x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                            IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                            StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                            StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                            Opacity="0"
                            StrokeDashOffset="0.5"/>

                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="60"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="60"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TextLabel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0"/>
                                                <DoubleAnimation
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                            To="1"
                                            Duration="0"/>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetName="OutlineGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundCheckedGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Content" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource AppBarItemPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked"/>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

the style I got from this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn481531.aspx

what else do I have to change?

Comment: This question showed me how to change the colors throughout the app, with the first code snippets from `App.xaml`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ContentPresenter line is missing the 'Content' property. Change the TargetType from ButtonBase to AppBarButton in both places and add "Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" to the ContentPresenter properties and you should then see the icon.

Your style is quite different from the default AppBarButton style. Unless I am missing something on what you are trying to do, I would recommend copying the entire style from:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn481531.aspx
and using that.

Comment: His style is copied from the Windows 8 version of the AppBarButtonStyle, I believe.